# Como inserir um breakpoint em Javascript pelo código

Tags: javascript, debug

Eu sei que é possível marcar uma linha como breakpoint usando Dev Tools, mas é possível invocar o debugger do navegador direto do código?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a palavra-chave `debugger`

```
function(){
   debugger; // quando estiver no modo de debug (F12) o cursor irá parar aqui
   alert("Is me...");
}
```

Comment: o devtools deve estar aberto